# Meaning of せないかんのよ

Tags: words, verbs, expressions

Reading *Tokyo Ghoul* I found this sentence:

> カミさんやらチビたちにまだまだ家族サービス**せないかん**のよ

After looking around I more or less understand it, expect the せないかん part: I'm guessing のよ are just ending particles and せない is a form of させない/causative, but I can't understand the かん part (which I'm not sure if it's かん, or か + ん).

In the manga is translated something like "Wife and children, I still have to work for you", and automatic translation agrees with "I still have to do family service for my wife and the little ones", but I was unable to find how せないかん gives that meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably Kansai dialect (or some western dialect). せないかん means しないといけない "have to do" in standard Japanese (deriving from せねばいかぬ to せにゃいかん to せないかん, perhaps?)

Here in Kansai (esp. Kyoto and Osaka as far as I know) we also say せなあかん、しなあかん、しないかん, or せんとあかん、せんといかん to mean that.

せな・しな・せんと means しないと・しなければ
あかん・いかん means いけない